# ASP.NET MVC Data Validation for Phone Number

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

hope you are doing well, 
I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am doing data validation for **phoneNumber** attribute which is of type **int**.

I want that the phone number to start from 0 and after that 9 digits long but it is important to start from 0.

So, I made this regular expression
^[0]{1}[0-9]{9}$

but the issue is that whenever the http post request comes and I see the data, I figured out that the phone number does not start from zero and start from the number after the 0. Like this

0557998765  (This is what is supposed to appear)
557998765   (unfortunately that is what appearing)

Can anyone help?
This is the code for phoneNumber attribute in my Model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a phone number")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression("^[0]{1}[0-9]{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Phone Number must be 10 Digits Long.")]
public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your property need to be `string`, not `int`

Comment: Sorry but that will make the phone number attribute to accepts characters

Comment: Not with your regex it wont. An a `int` cannot being with `0` (unless it is the number zero).

Comment: int will omit the 0. You can take that as string and then use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this line instead of your line:

```
[RegularExpression("^(0)(\d{9})$", ErrorMessage = "Phone Number must be 10 Digits Long.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

a 32 bit integer is not big enough to hold the value of a phone number if the
first digit is greater than '2'.  the maximum being 2147483647.
So if you phone number starts with a 3 or greater it won't validate for sure.
this field needs to be a string.